# Jenkins giving FileNotFoundException error

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

My file structure is -

- src>test>java>TestClass.java
- testFiles>FileA.json

In the TestClass.java -

```
InputStream outputStream = new FileInputStream("testfiles/FileA.json");
```

The test works fine when I run it as a JUnit in Eclipse or via terminal (Tested on Mac and Windows) -

```
mvn clean test
```

But when the same code is executed in Jenkins, I get the error -

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: testfiles/ExpectedJSON.json (No such file or directory)
```

Any suggestions on what could be the reason for Jenkins to give this error?

Comment: Have you tried setting the path to "../../../testfiles/FileA.json"

Comment: That causes mvn test and JUnit run to fail.

Comment: I tried checking the permissions of the file. But they are not restrictions in Jenkins I could find that would cause such a problem.

Comment: Is it because of the JSON file type?

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when Jenkins is running on top of an operating system with a case-sensitive filesystem, and the filename is correctly spelled but you have mistakenly substituted an upper-case letter for a lower-case letter, or a lower-case letter for an upper-case letter. This problem is in no way specific to Jenkins - it would affect any software - including your production code, if it has the same kind of errors.